# How can I get my API to generate my desired multi-tiered JSON scaffolding?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, json.net

This is what I want my JSON object to look like. **Note: the JSON below includes an 'artworks' node, but I am not actually able to generate this. This is the problem that I am trying to solve.**

```
{
    "idArtist": 2,
    "artistName": "Alice Waters",
    "indexArtworks": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "idArtist": 2,
            "idArtwork": 1,
            "artworks": [
                {
                    "idArtwork": 1,
                    "artworkTitle": "The Collaborative Artwork",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Pasted below is a diagram of my table structure. The blue arrow represents an existing FK. **The Orange arrow represents a nonexistant FK that would be a circular reference.** Based on my current knowledge of how the .NET Core Web API JSON scaffolding is generated, in order to create a JSON sub-sub-node using the `_context.<Object>.Include().ThenInclude()` API, I would need to define the orange-arrow FK. But this would introduce a circular reference in the DB, and my attempt to create this FK resulted in an error.

[image]

**This is my table structure, including FKs:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Artists](
    [ID_Artist] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Artist_Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Artists] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_Artist] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Artworks](
    [ID_Artwork] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Artwork_Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Artworks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_Artwork] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Index_Artworks](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_Artwork] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_Artist] [int] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Index_Artworks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Index_Artworks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__Index_Art__ID_Ar__1C1305F7] FOREIGN KEY([ID_Artwork])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Artworks] ([ID_Artwork])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Index_Artworks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__Index_Art__ID_Ar__1C1305F7]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Index_Artworks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__Index_Art__ID_Ar__1D072A30] FOREIGN KEY([ID_Artist])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Artists] ([ID_Artist])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Index_Artworks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__Index_Art__ID_Ar__1D072A30]
GO
```

**This is my Artist object in the Web API.**

```
    public partial class Artists
    {
        public Artists()
        {
            IndexArtworks = new HashSet<IndexArtworks>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<IndexArtworks> IndexArtworks { get; set; }
    }
```

**This is where I am issuing the HttpGet in the Web API.** I have pointed out the invalid line below. I realize that this is because the Artist object does not have the orange FK.

```
        // GET: api/Artists/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Artists>> GetArtists(int id)
        {
            var artists = await _context.Artists
                .Include(i => i.IndexArtworks)
                    .ThenInclude(i => i.Artworks) // <----------- this is not valid.
                .Where(i => i.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (artists == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return artists;
        }
```

**My question:** What do I need to change in the the API request, the Artist object in the API, or the tables and their relationships in order to include the "artworks" sub-sub node in the JSON?

**Edits -----------------------------------------**

@Guru Stron: 
Not sure if I understand your suggestion - please correct me if I'm wrong. The FK between `Index_Artworks` and `Artworks` points from `Index_Artworks` to `Artworks`. I would need to create an FK that points in the opposite direction, but the DB won't allow it (and it's a circular ref, so it's bad design).

In case your suggestion does not involve creating the orange-arrow FK, I made the following update to my `IndexArtworks` object in the API layer: I added a HashSet reference to `Artworks` and added the `virtual ICollection<Artworks>`. When I uncommented the `.ThenInclude(i => i.Artworks)` in my ArtistController and ran the API, it gave me the following error: `SqlException: Invalid column name 'IndexArtworksId'. Invalid column name 'IndexArtworksId'.` I don't know what this is about, because I searched the solution for `IndexArtworksId` and could not find it.

```
public partial class IndexArtworks
    {
        public IndexArtworks()
        {
            Artworks = new HashSet<Artworks>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdArtwork { get; set; }
        public int IdArtist { get; set; }
        public bool AVisibleYn { get; set; }
        public string AVisibleIdAdmin { get; set; }

        public virtual Artists IdArtistNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Artworks IdArtworkNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Artworks> Artworks { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can see you already have FK in your db between `IndexArtworks` and `Artworks` then why just don't add the reference property to your `IndexArtworks` entity?

Comment: @GuruStron I edited my post with my attempt to do what you suggested, but unfortunately it's not working. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Remove `public virtual ICollection<Artworks> Artworks { get; set; }` and use `ThenInclude(ia => ia.IdArtworkNavigation)`

Comment: yep, you nailed it. Thank you so much. Do you want to edit your submitted answer so I can approve it?

Comment: Updated answer and was glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the orange relation to use `ThenInclude`. You already have FK from `IndexArtworks` to `Artworks` so this should be fine:

```
class IndexArtworks
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ID_Artist { get; set; }
    public int ID_Artwork { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ID_Artist")]
    public virtual Artists Artist { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ID_Artwork")]
    public virtual Artworks Artwork { get; set; }
}
```

And query:

```
 var artists = await _context.Artists
            .Include(i => i.IndexArtworks)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Artwork) 
            .Where(i => i.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**UPD**

With your naming conventions this should look like:

```
public partial class IndexArtworks
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdArtwork { get; set; }
    public int IdArtist { get; set; }
    public bool AVisibleYn { get; set; }
    public string AVisibleIdAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual Artists IdArtistNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Artworks IdArtworkNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

And query:

```
 var artists = await _context.Artists
            .Include(i => i.IndexArtworks)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.IdArtworkNavigation) 
            .Where(i => i.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```